# How to run stylelint on the style tag written inside a Vue file

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, stylelint

I'm configuring the stylelints for the styles in my Vue project. For the independent `.css` and `.scss` files, I did this using [stylelint-scss](https://github.com/stylelint-scss/stylelint-scss/tree/278f4e6a2ceda797eda91244783ada3a7fd8d2ba) package. But I'm facing difficulty to configure this for the style tags written inside my vue component like below.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
defineProps({})
</script>

<template class="container">
  <p>Sample p tag</p>
</template>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container {
  p {
    color: white;
  }
  @media (min-width: 500px) {  // Prohibited as per scss/media-feature-value-dollar-variable rule
    color: green;
  }
}
</style>
```

I have to run stylelint for the styles written inside `<style lang="scss" scoped></style>` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To lint CSS, SCSS and SCSS within Vue SFCs, you can use Stylelint's [`overrides`](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure#overrides) configuration property to extend a combination of shared configs:

- [`stylelint-config-standard`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard) - the official standard config (maintained by the Stylelint team)
- [`stylelint-config-standard-scss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard-scss) - an adaption of the standard config for linting SCSS (maintained by the SCSS community)
- [`stylelint-config-standard-vue`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard-vue) - an adaption of the standard config for linting Vue SFCs (maintained by the Vue community)

First, install the dependencies:

```
npm i --save-dev postcss-html stylelint-config-standard-vue stylelint-config-standard stylelint-config-standard-scss
```

Then update your Stylelint configuration to:

```
{
  "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard"],
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.scss", "**/*.scss"],
      "extends": ["stylelint-config-standard-scss"]
    },
    {
      "files": ["*.vue", "**/*.vue"],
      "extends": [
        "stylelint-config-standard-scss",
        "stylelint-config-standard-vue/scss"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally, run Stylelint on your CSS, SCSS and Vue files:

```
npx stylelint "**/*.{css,scss,vue}"
```

This configuration tells Stylelint to use the official config for CSS files, the SCSS community config for SCSS files and both the SCSS and Vue community configs for SCSS within Vue files.

> For the independent .css and .scss files,  did this using `stylelint-scss` package

The `stylelint-config-standard-scss` shared config bundles the `stylelint-scss` plugin pack for you, so you don't need to include it in your configuration.

Each community config also bundles the relevant custom syntax for each language or container: postcss-scss and postcss-html for SCSS and Vue files, respectively.